# Flash Frame redirection to html page

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a flash file . In last frame i want to redirect it to a website.

My problem is that I am not able to find the last frame. so how can i perform this ?
please suggest me ...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by simply adding some ActionScript to your last (or any other) frame:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.somewebsite.com"));
```

Finding the last frame should not be all too difficult when you have the .fla file?